# pip Could not find an activated virtualenv (required)

Tags: python, pip

I have the following in my .bash_profile

```
gpip(){
    PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip3 "$@"
}
```

But when I type gpip instal... I get: `Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).`

Tried, as suggested:

```
Last login: Thu Jul  5 03:06:42 on ttys008
~ ❯❯❯ export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
~ ❯❯❯ gpip(){
>      PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip3 "$@"
>  }
~ ❯❯❯ pip3 install foo
Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
~ ❯❯❯ gpip install foo                                                                                                                                        
Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue. I just defined your function and it works fine here:

```
nosklo@stackoverflow:~$ export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
nosklo@stackoverflow:~$ gpip(){
>     PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip3 "$@"
> }
nosklo@stackoverflow:~$ pip3 install foo
Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
nosklo@stackoverflow:~$ gpip install foo
Collecting foo
^COperation cancelled by user
nosklo@stackoverflow:~$
```

Comment: Hi I was away on holiday. I'm still getting that. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @user432024 I can't fix what I can't reproduce, as you can see in the output I put in my answer, it works fine here

Comment: I understand. But is there some env variable I can look for or some script, check the path location etc?

I think it's because I did gpip update pip or something?

Comment: @user432024 can you type the exact commands I did in your shell, in the exact same sequence, and then paste output?